# Spring Boot: Relocation of a configuration file at run time

Tags: java, spring-boot

Hy, I'm working with springboot and I have a problem.

I have a file myFile.yml that is loaded from the classpath: **myApp**/myFile.yml.

The problem is that there is another project, over which I have no control, reads the file from classpath:myFile.yml

The idea is to copy the file in classpath:myApp/myFile.yml so the external jar can also read it.

Is there any way to copy the file, while the beans are loaded, from /**myApp**/myFile.yml
 to /myFile.yml?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you want load the properties files from external ?

Comment: I must move the properties to the new directory and the embeded jar can not find it. I have no problem reading the file, I just want to copy it from the new location to the old one when spring loads the beans. Just so that jar does not complain. :)